# Identifying Late binding in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have an application which had been migrated to VB to VB.NET. Now in few places in VB there were code written for using Trim operation on a non-string Datatype. The code runs well in VB but the same produce error on migrated code in VB.NET.Following is the code snippet

```
dr["N0"].Trim() ----where "NO" is an integer or any non-string DataType
```

I want to identify these places in my migrated VB.NET code base. How I can do that without minimal effort? Any efficient idea or technique?

Comment: If `dr["N0"]` is an `int` what is `Trim()` supposed to do? Does that even compile in VB.NET?

Comment: So you want to find instances of the use of Trim()? Or anyplace in the code that will cause errors due to late binding? The former is easy using Search; the latter....

Comment: Since VB.NET allow late binding there will be no compile error. The error crops up in runtime

Comment: @user1672097 you can change that with `Option Strict`

Answer (score 1):

Just gate these with TypeOf http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx, you could even use a Debug.Alert(); so as you're going through the program you get alerted (in debug mode).